# Bootstrap 2 navbar dropdown menu stacking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with my bootstrap navbar.

I have 2 navbar, in 1 page. In the second navbar, i put a dropdown li tag.

When i click it, the UL tag for the dropdown menu is hidden behind the next div.

But i copy the EXACT dropdown li tag to the first navbar, it works perfectly.

what did i do wrong ?

[image]

GitHub : https://github.com/MarcelAng92/dealer_toyota_bali

```
note : Please see ONLY INDEX.HTML !
```

Comment: Oh, from the github, its different from the image i give, because i remove the carousel to highlight the problem.

Comment: can you upload it in a JSFiddle or Plnkr.. It would be easy for us to look and find the issue